# JSF component privacy between users

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Assume that there are two pages named as login and homepage. A pre-defined login filter is checking our session map whether it has an authenticated user object, and enters if it has.

Rendering components with a bean value is the easiest way to handle roles like admin - user - guest etc. But it is not differing more specific user roles for a web-site.

Wanted to create an extra privacy layer that lays between users. For example, if two user have a friendship, they will see each others profile completely. Meanwhile, another irrelevant user should be blocked to see those whole user profiles without being in a friendship with those users.

Actually, I don't want to use any third party library like spring security etc. How can implement it and combine it with general roles, with using pure JSF ?

Comment: Well strictly speaking, this is not something JSF will cater for. This is more a general design issue. I'd start by maintaining a DAO that will verify if a `user_id` is in a list of approved viewers per user. Such logic, you'll place in a vanilla JEE filter, or in the `preRenderView` event for the profile page